# Create 2 HashMap within a loop to compare the values

Tags: java, hashmap

I am reading a txt file of multiple pipe delimited records, each token of records corresponds to unique key and different value. I need to compare each record values (with same keys). To compare this I want to use HashMap to store first record then will iterate and store second record. After that will compare both hashmap to see if both contains similar values. But I am not sure how to manage or create 2 hashma within same loop while reading the txt file.
Example :
txt file as below

```
A|B|C|D|E
A|B|C|O|E 
O|O|C|D|E
```

Each token of each record will be stored against unique key as below 
first record

```
map.put(1, A);
map.put(2, B);
map.put(3, C);
map.put(4, D);
map.put(5, E);
```

Second record

```
map.put(1, A);
map.put(2, B);
map.put(3, C);
map.put(4, O);
map.put(5, E);
```

third record

```
map.put(1, O);
map.put(2, O);
map.put(3, C);
map.put(4, D);
map.put(5, E);
```

When I read each record in java using input stream, in same loop of reading records how can I create 2 hashmap of 2 different record to compare.

```
FileInputStream fstream;
            fstream = new FileInputStream("C://PROJECTS//sampleInput.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
                //Read File Line By Line
             String line1=null;
             while ((line1 = br.readLine()) != null){            
              Scanner scan = new Scanner(line1).useDelimiter("\\|");
              while(scan.hasNext()){
                // reading each token of the record

                // how to create 2 hashmap of 2 records to compare.. or is there any simple way to compare each incoming records 
              }
              printIt(counter);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're thinking a little bit too complicated here by creating a new `HashMap` for each read line. I'd rather suggest to create an `ArrayList<String>` (or some other kind of 1-dimensional data structure) and store all read lines sequentially. After that you can iterate over this data structure and compare each value against each other by using string methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count number of diffs you can use the following example:

```
int diffCount = 0;
String fileName = "test.psv";
try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), '|')) {
    String[] prevLine = reader.readNext();
    String[] nextLine;
    while (prevLine != null && (nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        if (!Arrays.equals(prevLine, nextLine)) {
            diffCount++;
        }
        prevLine = nextLine;
    }
    logger.info("Diff count: {}", diffCount);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    logger.error("enable to find file {}", fileName, e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Got IO exception", e);
}
```

If for some reasons you really want to create two hashmap you can try to do this like this:

```
int diffCount = 0;
String fileName = "test.psv";
try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), '|')) {
    Map<Integer, String> prevLine = readNextLine(reader);
    Map<Integer, String> nextLine;
    while (prevLine != null && (nextLine = readNextLine(reader)) != null) {
        if (!prevLine.equals(nextLine)) {
            diffCount++;
        }
        prevLine = nextLine;
    }
    logger.info("Diff count: {}", diffCount);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    logger.error("enable to find file {}", fileName, e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Got IO exception", e);
}

private Map<Integer, String> readNextLine(CSVReader reader) throws IOException {
    String[] nextLine = reader.readNext();
    return nextLine != null ? convert2map(nextLine) : null;
}

private Map<Integer, String> convert2map(String[] nextLine) {
    return IntStream.range(0, nextLine.length)
            .boxed()
            .collect(toMap(identity(), (index) -> nextLine[index]));
}
```